# Zoom in and Zoom out on Camera View Using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, camera, zooming, uipinchgesturerecognizer

How to Apply Zoom in and Zoom out On Camera view Using UIPinchGestureRecognizer and AVCaptureDevice. 
It is Not Zooming properly.
Zoom Out is Not Working in My below Code :

```
 AVCaptureDevice *device =[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:
                                                       AVMediaTypeVideo];
 AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format = device.activeFormat;
 CGFloat maxZoomFactor = format.videoMaxZoomFactor;
 const CGFloat pinchVelocityDividerFactor = 2.0f;

 if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || pinchRecognizer.state ==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
 {
     NSError *error = nil;
      if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
      {
         CGFloat desiredZoomFactor = device.videoZoomFactor +
             atan2f(pinchRecognizer.velocity, pinchVelocityDividerFactor);

          // Check if desiredZoomFactor fits required range from 1.0
                                   //to activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor
          if((1.0 <= pinchRecognizer.scale) && (2.5 >= pinchRecognizer.scale))
          device.videoZoomFactor = pinchRecognizer.scale * pinchRecognizer.scale;  

        [device unlockForConfiguration];
      }
      else
      {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
      }
 }  
}
```

Please help anyone.
Thanks

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245127/uipinchgesturerecognizer-make-zoom-in-location-of-fingers-not-only-center

Comment: But in That they have given for Image or a View i Want using device VideoZoom Factor

Comment: @kishor where did you added pinchgesture? I have to implement zoom but don't know where should i add pinch gesture?

Answer (score 4):

// PinchGesture Recognizer method define

```
- (void)handlePinchZoom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchRecognizer
 {
     AVCaptureDevice *device =[AVCaptureDevicedefaultDeviceWithMediaType:
                                                       AVMediaTypeVideo];
     AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format = device.activeFormat;
     CGFloat maxZoomFactor = format.videoMaxZoomFactor;
     NSArray *formats = device.formats;
     const CGFloat pinchVelocityDividerFactor = 2.0f;
     if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || pinchRecognizer.state ==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
     {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
        {
           CGFloat desiredZoomFactor = device.videoZoomFactor +
           atan2f(pinchRecognizer.velocity, pinchVelocityDividerFactor);

           device.videoZoomFactor =   MAX(1.0, MIN(desiredZoomFactor,
                                          device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor));
           [device unlockForConfiguration];
        } 
       else
       {
         NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
       }
     }
  }
```