# iOS Pinch Zoom Start from Previous Scale

Tags: ios, swift, pinchzoom

I want to do a pinch/zoom having the zoom start at the current scale.  I have tried the following code:

```
@objc func pinchedView(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    if (recognizer.state == .ended)  {
        lastScale = 1.0
        return
    }

    let scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - recognizer.scale)
    let zoomInAction = SKAction.scale(to: cameraNode.yScale + scale, duration: 0.25)
    lastScale = recognizer.scale
    cameraNode.run(zoomInAction)
}
```

The problem is that it keeps getting smaller and smaller no matter which way I pinch.  How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might instead want to initialize lastScale to 1.0 when your gesture begins.

Look at the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245127/uipinchgesturerecognizer-make-zoom-in-location-of-fingers-not-only-center) to this question.